# R: How to Simulate a Queue

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I am trying to learn how to simulate a queue.

For example:

- Suppose a customer arrives in a cafe every poisson(lambda1) minutes
- There is one server (i.e. cafe employee)
- The server finishes an order every poisson(lambda2) minutes.

I want to simulate and plot over a period of time:

- number of orders completed
- length of line
- total time waited (i.e. from entry to order completion) by the customer that just got served

From mathematics, I know that differences between Poisson arrivals have an Exponential Distribution. If I choose some values of lambda1 and lambda2 - I can simulate all the arrival times and service times prior to running the loop. This is because the arrival times and service times are completely independent from one another and relative to each other :

```
library(ggplot2)

# Parameters
lambda1 <- 5  # customer arrival rate
lambda2 <- 7  # order completion rate
time_period <- 1000  # total time period

# Initialize 
arrival_times <- cumsum(rexp(time_period, rate = 1/lambda1))
service_times <- rexp(time_period, rate = 1/lambda2)
completion_times <- numeric(time_period)
queue_length <- numeric(time_period)
total_wait_time <- numeric(time_period)
```

I can then try to simulate this queue over 1000 time points:

```
# Simulation
for (i in 1:time_period) {
    if (i == 1) {
        completion_times[i] <- arrival_times[i] + service_times[i]
    } else {
        if (arrival_times[i] < completion_times[i-1]) {
            completion_times[i] <- completion_times[i-1] + service_times[i]
        } else {
            completion_times[i] <- arrival_times[i] + service_times[i]
        }
    }
    queue_length[i] <- sum(arrival_times <= completion_times[i]) - i
    total_wait_time[i] <- completion_times[i] - arrival_times[i]
}


df <- data.frame(Time = 1:time_period,
                 Completed_Orders = 1:time_period,
                 Queue_Length = queue_length,
                 Total_Wait_Time = total_wait_time)
```

Then, I can plot the results:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Completed_Orders, color = "Completed Orders")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Queue_Length, color = "Queue Length")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Total_Wait_Time, color = "Total Wait Time")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Total Wait Time")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Completed Orders" = "blue", "Queue Length" = "red", "Total Wait Time" = "green")) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Completed Orders / Queue Length",
       title = "Queue Simulation", color = "Legend") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I think this is correct - this is because the number of orders can never decrease and can only increase/stay the same. The blue line on my graph is always increasing.

**My Question:** Now, suppose there are 2 servers. The customers line up in one line and go to the server that becomes first available. If both servers are available at the same time, the customer picks randomly.

I am not sure how I can modify my code to "split" the flow of customers and re-direct them to either server.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe your time variable is actually order number. I’m not sure that’s what you want.

Comment: I think your code is incorrect, because the service rate should drop to zero when there are no customers in the system, and I don't see that -- but I might have missed it.  When you go to two servers, there are three possible service rates:  0 when empty, `lambda2` when one customer is being served, and `2*lambda2` when both servers are busy. So you should add another variable representing number of busy servers, taking values 0, 1, or 2.  And instead of looping over time periods, loop over customers, and keep running until you reach time 1000.

Comment: Did you consider using [simmer](https://r-simmer.org/articles/simmer-04-bank-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think your simulation is quite right. The completed orders should not ascend in a straight line if the service time varies by customer. We should only see this pattern with a fixed service time and a queue that always has customers in it.

If we have multiple servers, one way to handle the calculation is to keep a vector of the same length as the number of servers to keep track of the time at which each server is next available. This will start as a vector of zeros.

When a customer arrives, we find which server will be next available (i.e. the one with the lowest "next available time"). If one or more servers has a "next available time" that is less than or equal to the arrival time, there is a server available immediately and the wait time is 0. The completion time is just the customer arrival time plus the customer service time. We then set the chosen server's "next available time" to the completion time.

If the next available server time is *after* a customer's arrival, then the wait time is the difference between the customer arrival and the next available server time. We then just add the next available server time and the service time to get the completion time. Again, the chosen server's "next available time" is set to the completion time.

This sequence is repeated for all customers, after which we have a vector of arrival times, completion times, and wait times. If we put all these vectors in a data frame, we can work out the queue size by pivoting into long format, sorting by time and just counting up the number of customers in the shop at any time. We need to subtract the number of servers to find the number of *unserved* customers in the shop at any time to get the queue size.

Here is an implementation of this algorithm wrapped up in a function:

```r
model_queue <- function(arrival_times, service_times, n_servers) {

  if(length(arrival_times) != length(service_times)) {
    stop('length of "arrivals" must equal length of "service_time"')
  }
  n              <- length(arrival_times)
  complete       <- numeric(n)
  waits          <- numeric(n)
  server_free_at <- numeric(n_servers)
  
  for(i in seq(n)) {
      server <- which.min(server_free_at)
      if(arrival_times[i] > server_free_at[server]) {
        waits[i] <- 0
        server_free_at[server] <- arrival_times[i] + service_times[i]
        complete[i] <- arrival_times[i] + service_times[i]
      } else {
      waits[i] <- server_free_at[server] - arrival_times[i]
      complete[i] <- arrival_times[i] + waits[i] + service_times[i]
      server_free_at[server] <-  server_free_at[server] + service_times[i]
      }
  }

  data.frame(arrival_times, complete, customer = seq(n), waits) |>
    tidyr::pivot_longer(1:2, names_to = "event", values_to = "time") |>
    dplyr::arrange(time) |>
    transform(completed_orders = cumsum(event == "complete"),
              customers = cumsum(event == "arrival_times")) |>
    transform(queue = pmax(0, customers - completed_orders - n_servers)) |>
    transform(waits = ifelse(event == "complete", NA, waits))
}
```

Let's take some reproducible sample data:

```r
set.seed(1)

lambda1 <- 5
lambda2 <- 7
n <- 100

arrivals     <- cumsum(rexp(n, 1/lambda1))
service_time <- rexp(n, 1/lambda2)
```

Let's use this data and model a queue with a single server, then examine the output:

```r
queue_df1 <- model_queue(arrivals, service_time, n_servers = 1)

head(queue_df1)
#>   customer     waits         event      time completed_orders customers queue
#> 1        1  0.000000 arrival_times  3.775909                0         1     0
#> 2        2  7.390689 arrival_times  9.684123                0         2     1
#> 3        3 10.275599 arrival_times 10.412657                0         3     2
#> 4        4 12.719607 arrival_times 11.111633                0         4     3
#> 5        5 13.196461 arrival_times 13.291976                0         5     4
#> 6        1        NA      complete 17.074813                1         5     3
```

And with two servers:

```r
queue_df2 <- model_queue(arrivals, service_time, n_servers = 2)
head(queue_df2)
#>   customer    waits         event      time completed_orders customers queue
#> 1        1 0.000000 arrival_times  3.775909                0         1     0
#> 2        2 0.000000 arrival_times  9.684123                0         2     0
#> 3        3 2.884909 arrival_times 10.412657                0         3     1
#> 4        4 5.328917 arrival_times 11.111633                0         4     2
#> 5        5 3.782836 arrival_times 13.291976                0         5     3
#> 6        2       NA      complete 13.297566                1         5     2
```

We can plot the outcome as follows:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(queue_df1, aes(time, queue)) +
  geom_step(aes(color = "Queue length")) +
  geom_step(aes(y = completed_orders, color = "Completed orders")) +
  geom_step(aes(y = waits, color = "Wait time"), 
            data = subset(queue_df1, !is.na(waits))) +
  geom_textvline(aes(xintercept = max(time[event == "arrival_times"]),
                 label = "Last arrival"), vjust = -0.3, hjust = 0.75) +
  scale_color_brewer(NULL, palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(queue_df2, aes(time, queue)) +
  geom_step(aes(color = "Queue length")) +
  geom_step(aes(y = completed_orders, color = "Completed orders")) +
  geom_step(aes(y = waits, color = "Wait time"), 
            data = subset(queue_df2, !is.na(waits))) +
  geom_textvline(aes(xintercept = max(time[event == "arrival_times"]),
                     label = "Last arrival"), vjust = -0.3, hjust = 0.75) +
  scale_color_brewer(NULL, palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

We can see that with two servers, there is far less of a queue or wait time.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed and wonderful answer! I will now study your answer and try to adapt it for other situations!

Comment: one question I had about this - just to confirm: the green line (wait time) is the total time (from entering the cafe to order completion) spent waiting by the customer who just got served?

Comment: @stats_noob  no, it's the time waiting in the queue.  You can add the service time to this value to get the total wait if you prefer.

Comment: thank you for your reply! So just to clarify, the green line is "expected time to be served for the last person in the queue"? Or am I still misunderstanding this?

Comment: Yes, that's right @stats_noob